# No instance for (Show a) arising

Tags: haskell

ghci is giving me the error "No instance for (Show a) arising from use of 'commaSeperated'"

What im trying to do is define a show for my data Set that uses curly braces instead of square. What am I doing wrong here?

```
data Set a = Set [a]

instance Show (Set a) where
    show (Set a) = "{" ++ init (commaSeparated a) ++ "}"

commaSeparated :: Show a => [a] -> [Char]
commaSeparated [] = ""
commaSeparated (x:xs) = show x ++ "," ++ commaSeparated xs
```

Comment: Also try `commaSeparated = intercalate "," . map show` after `import Data.List`. It will not output the tailing comma, so that you won't have to use `init` to remove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `instance` declaration does not have a context. Rewrite it as `instance Show a => Show (Set a)`.